# javascript: how i can define is object jQuery object or something else object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, i have two objects:

```
var object1 = $('div');
var object2 = {};
```

How i can define is this jQuery object, or not?

for javascript version < 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var abc={};

if(typeof(abc.jquery)=="undefined"){

console.log("object is not a jquery object");

}else{

console.log("object is a jQuery object");

}
```

if object is jQuery object then

```
objectIdentifier.jquery =< version of jQuery>
```

Comment: Thank you, i find it on moderator's question link, and i will ise it

Answer (score 2):

Try checking it by using instanceof

`var isJqueryObject = object1 instanceof jQuery`

Comment: yes, but this is JavaScript 1.4

Answer (score 0):

try it this way `var isJQ = ( object1 && jQuery == object.constructor);`